# Save only hours and minutes in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

Actually I am inserting some rows into a SQL Server 2005 database with the help of c#.
In my datetime columns I want to save only hours and minutes.

Please let me know how can I insert by both methods through SQL and also through C#.

Thanks

Comment: I found this snippet of SQL code that turns a date into the date truncated to minutes: `dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In Sqlserver you can easily handle it,By using the following code

`ist step`-->
Declare two valriable
`2nd step`-->
write this piece of code

```
  declare @hour int,@minute int
         set @hour=(SELECT DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()));
         set @minute=(SELECT DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()));
         print @hour
         print @minute
```

i am using print to show the hour and minute .you can directly insert it into database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking to use a DATETIME field, you can't just store hours and minutes in SQL 2005. What SQL will store is a date time like: `1900-01-01 HH:MM:00.000`. When you get the date out you need to trim off the bits that you don't care about.

2 Other options which I wouldn't recommend is to:

- use 2 integer fields - Hours and Minutes; or
- 1 integer field (minutes since midnight).

This is likely to cause a lot of other   problems, so you shouldn't do it

Comment: actually I need to compare only time stored in database (not date) with the time in my code file which is actually c#

Comment: You can compare the two dates and just get the time difference. Eg. 1900-01-01 12:00 < 1900-01-01 13:00 == true

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for C#..It will work..

```
String.Format("{0:t}", dt);
```

Comment: actually my inserting field is datetime, but you gave me a string format